# Upload file with IFRAME, the file don't get to the server

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Following my code:

HTML:

```
<form id="test" action="javascript:test()" method="post">
<input name="image" type="file" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function test(){
   iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");  
   iframe.name = "iframe_upload";
   iframe.src="test.php";
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
   document.getElementById("test").target = "iframe_upload";
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_FILES["image"])){
     echo 'exist';
     exit();
  }
?>
```

Where is the error? I'm sure the problem is in javascript, it would be easy to take off without the javascript dynamically create the iframe, but I must use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of problems with that but nothing major,

firstly in order to post files you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`to your form

seccondly the `action` of the form should be the file you are posting to (the iframe source) and the javascript should be run from `onsubmit`

finally you need to give the iframe an `id` for cross browser support

i end up with this

JS:

```
function test(){
     iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");  
     iframe.name = "iframe_upload";
     iframe.id = "iframe_upload"; //some browsers target by id not name
     document.body.appendChild(iframe);
     document.getElementById("test").target = "iframe_upload";
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="test"   method="post" target="iframe_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="javascript:test()" action="test.php">
<input name="image" type="file" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot, i have a question, with old browser like IE6 the intere page do a refresh. How to prevent this?

Comment: `onsubmit="javascript:test(); return false;"` i havn't tested this but in theory it should work